# Apache Poi Apply Gradient Color to Cell

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

i have been searching the web and found no real good example for applying a gradient color to an excel sheet cell using Apache Poi.

The example I found are pretty old and the classes not really exist anymore in the current Apache Poi version. I'm currently using Apache Poi version 3.16.

Can somebody point out the steps which are needed to apply a gradient color to excel sheet using the poi library. All hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is always still not a possibility to set gradient cell fills using the default actual `apache poi` versions.

So I suspect that the code you found was for `XSSF` (`*.xlsx`) and for the code you found it was just not mentioned that this code needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` or `poi-ooxml-full-*.jar` in the class path as mentioned in [faq-N10025](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

The following example works but also needs the full jar of all of the schemas in the class path as mentioned in [faq-N10025](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

It first sets pattern fill settings to the `CellStyle` only to have some fill to get the fill index from it. Then it gets the low level `CTFill` used in this `CellStyle`. An then it unsets the pattern fill and then it sets the gradient fill.

To get informations about how to use `CTFill` one needs download the sources of `ooxml-schemas` and do `javadoc`. There is no API documentation for `ooxml-schemas` public available.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFill;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTGradientFill;

public class CreateExcelCellGradientFillColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

  XSSFCellStyle cellstyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  //set pattern fill settings only to have some fill to get the fill index from it
  cellstyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

  //get fill index used in this CellStyle
  int fillidx = (int)cellstyle.getCoreXf().getFillId();

  //get the low level CTFill used in this CellStyle
  CTFill ctfill = workbook.getStylesSource().getFillAt(fillidx).getCTFill();
System.out.println(ctfill);

  //unset the pattern fill
  ctfill.unsetPatternFill();

  //now low level set the gradient fill
  byte[] rgb1 = new byte[3];
  rgb1[0] = (byte) 0; // red
  rgb1[1] = (byte) 0; // green
  rgb1[2] = (byte) 255; // blue

  byte[] rgb2 = new byte[3];
  rgb2[0] = (byte) 255; // red
  rgb2[1] = (byte) 255; // green
  rgb2[2] = (byte) 255; // blue

  CTGradientFill ctgradientfill = ctfill.addNewGradientFill();
  ctgradientfill.setDegree(90.0);
  ctgradientfill.addNewStop().setPosition(0.0);
  ctgradientfill.getStopArray(0).addNewColor().setRgb(rgb1);
  ctgradientfill.addNewStop().setPosition(0.5);
  ctgradientfill.getStopArray(1).addNewColor().setRgb(rgb2);
  ctgradientfill.addNewStop().setPosition(1.0);
  ctgradientfill.getStopArray(2).addNewColor().setRgb(rgb1);
System.out.println(ctfill);

  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("");
  cell.setCellStyle(cellstyle);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelCellGradientFillColor.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that really clarifies my issues i have included th wrond Maven dependency in my project and because of that some classes could not be resolved.

I used  poi-ooxml-schemas as dependency which is wrong. Now changed to ooxml-schemas and all classes can be found. Thanks for your clarification.